# I need help with calculating probability

Tags: probability

I need help with this question:
Consider a loaded dice such that the probability to obtain an outcome of 1 is 2p/3, the probability of obtaining 2, 3, 4 or 5 is p each, and the probability of obtaining 6 is 3p/2. 
(1) Compute the average outcome of throwing the above loaded dice.
(2) Compute the variance in the outcome of throwing the above loaded dice

I have calculated p to be 6/37 and i've tried to do the other 2 questions but i don't know how to them

Comment: What goes wrong when you try to compute the mean and variance in the usual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E(X)= sum of x times the probability fx

I got 6/37 as well so should be right

therefore

fx(1) = 2(6/37)/3 = 4/37

fx(2) = fx(3) = fx(4) = fx(5) = 6/37

fx(6) = 3(6/37)/2 = 9/37

and they do add up to 1 so then

E(X) = 1(4/37) + 2(6/37) + 3(6/37) + 4(6/37) + 5(6/37) + 6(9/37) = 142/37 (3.837837....)

Then

Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2

[E(X)]^2 is just the square of the answer we just got, which is [142/37]^2

E(X^2) = 1(4/37) + 4(6/37) + 9(6/37) + 16(6/37) + 25(6/37) + 36(9/37) = 652/37

and so the Variance is (652/37) - ([142/37]^2) = 2.892622352 (approx 2.9)

Correct me if I'm wrong.